# Strange outcome in Sublime with ruby files

Tags: ruby, sublimetext2

I'm working with ruby files, when I press command+B to see the outcome, it says the syntax is wrong, but it looks like that is trying to use python instead of ruby. Please see the image below.

For example I have a ruby file called 'hello.rb'

Then I press Command+B

and the outcome is:

```
File "/Users/enriquesalceda/Library/Application Support/Sublime Text 3/Packages/User/hello.rb", line 1
puts "hello world!!!"
                    ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
[Finished in 0.1s with exit code 1]
[shell_cmd: python -u "/Users/enriquesalceda/Library/Application Support/Sublime Text 3/Packages/User/hello.rb"]
[dir: /Users/enriquesalceda/Library/Application Support/Sublime Text 3/Packages/User]
[path: /usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin]
```

Thank you.

Comment: I haven't used this option but: have you checked "Automatic"/"ruby" in a Tools/build system?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are right, your ST is using the wrong build system.

Try setting your build system to automatic. Tools -> Build System -> Automatic.

If that doesn't work, manually set the build system to ruby.  Tools -> Build System -> Ruby